# How to enforce soft deletes on postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, rule, soft-delete

I want to prevent sql row deletes on a table in a Postgres database, to ensure that there is no other way of deleting rows, other than soft deletes, which are in effect an update to the "active" column of the row being soft-deleted.

Could this be achieved using a Postgres sql rule or is there another means??

Code examples are appreciated.

Comment: yes - `ON DELETE DO INSTEAD` should do the thing

Comment: here are code examples: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrule.html

Comment: Is it possible to raise an error from a rule, as opposed to DO INSTEAD NOTHING

Comment: if you need logic, better use function delete_row(args) which would perform all actions, including exceptions, etc

Comment: Could you supply a code example of a simple function that takes no arguments an raises an exception ? It is not straight forward, as functions expect a return type

Comment: The following function will raise an error, but how do I invoke it in an INSTEAD clause? CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION throwIllegalDeleteException() RETURNS VOID AS $$
  BEGIN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'only soft deletes of accounts allowed';
  END;
  $$;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133572/discussion-between-murungu-and-vao-tsun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION enforce_soft_delete() RETURNS VOID AS $$ 
BEGIN 
RAISE EXCEPTION 'only soft deletes allowed'; 
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 


CREATE OR REPLACE RULE prevent_account_deletion AS ON DELETE 
TO account 
DO INSTEAD SELECT enforce_soft_delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`revoke`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html)

```
revoke update on the_table 
from public, another_role [cascade | restrict]
```